Login Redirection Issue in Express.js with Passport Authentication
I am developing an Express.js application and facing a persistent issue with user authentication. Despite successful user registration and confirmed entries in the database, the login process does not proceed as expected.
After users enter their credentials, the login script is supposed to redirect authenticated users to a dashboard. However, regardless of entering correct credentials, users are redirected back to the login page without any error message.
The session is supposed to be saved and reused, but users cannot access authenticated routes and are forced to log in repeatedly.
console log:
GET /stylesheets/loginStyle.css 200 0.852 ms - 2564
POST /account/login 302 1.858 ms - 72
GET /account/login 200 9.526 ms - 713
GET /stylesheets/loginStyle.css 304 0.475 ms - -
GET /account/login 304 1.962 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/loginStyle.css 200 0.795 ms - 2564

index.html:
  <% if (message.length > 0) { %>
      <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
    <% } %>
        
    <form action="/account/login" method="post">
        <h2>Admin Login</h2>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
        <br></br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <p>Don't have an account? <a href="/account/signup"> Signup!</a></p>
    </form>

passport local login:
 passport.use(
    "local-login",
    new LocalStrategy(
      {
        usernameField: "email",
        passwordField: "password",
        passReqToCallback: true,
      },
      function (req, email, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error in login: ", err);
            return done(err);
          }
          if (!user) {
            console.log("No user found with email: ", email);
            return done(
              null,
              false,
              req.flash("loginMessage", "No user found."),
            );
          }
          if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
            console.log("Wrong password for email: ", email);
            return done(
              null,
              false,
              req.flash("loginMessage", "Oops! Wrong password."),
            );
          }
          console.log("User authenticated successfully: ", user);
          return done(null, user);
        });
      },
    ),
  );

Route:
router.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local-login", {
    successRedirect: "/dashboard",
    failureRedirect: "/account/login",
    failureFlash: true,
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    // This code will not be executed on successful login
    // because the successRedirect will trigger first
    console.log("Successful login!");  // Optional for debugging
  }
);

// required for passport
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "finalExamKey",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { maxAge: 60000 * 60 }, // for example, 1 hour
  }),
);

I've ensured that the session cookie is set correctly with an appropriate max age.
The serialization and deserialization functions in Passport seem to be set up correctly.
Login and authentication routes are supposedly configured correctly, but the redirect fails.
Could anyone suggest what might be causing this issue or point out what I might be missing here? If additional specific parts of the code are needed to diagnose the problem, I'm happy to provide them under guidance.

Hi, It means the session is not being maintained, and every request creates a new session. Further more, the cookie carrying sessionID may not be getting saved into the client. This can be checked in Chrome at the option Developer Tools / Application/Cookies. There should be cookie stored here just after adding the first item. This may be the first point of check. Secondly, if it is a cross-site request sharing case, then the request to Registration in the client should have been invoked with credentials : 'include'. Please see if is also set.

Did you add the redirect url when you configure your project in cloud console?
If not add it .. if already added , check whether actual redirect url matches  with the url exist in project in google console
